# How to hide the figures on the coordinates in a High Chart graph?

Tags: highcharts

For example, I want to hide the `0` and `5` in the chart. How can I achieve that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a polar chart, that is the yAxis.  Disable the labels:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {enabled: false}
},
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qyERX/).